# How can I use the same piece of html with different data in AngularJS without duplication?

Tags: angularjs

I need the following:

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="person in row1">               
        <img data-ng-src="img/{{person.code}}.jpg">
        <h3>{{person.name}}</h3>
        <p>{{person.description}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="person in row2">        
        <img data-ng-src="img/{{person.code}}.jpg">
        <h3>{{person.name}}</h3>
        <p>{{person.description}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but I don't want to duplicate the html - I want to be able to pass in the two different arrays (row1 and row2) to `ng-include` or something similar. How can I do this in AngularJS?

Comment: did you try using directives for reusable items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the array of rows to another model and use **ng-repeat** in **ul** tag

In your controller:

```
$scope.rows = [row1, row2];
```

In your template:

```
<ul ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <li ng-repeat="person in row">               
        <img data-ng-src="img/{{person.code}}.jpg">
        <h3>{{person.name}}</h3>
        <p>{{person.description}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```